# Keep sub menu open

Tags: jquery, css

In this menu the sub categories slide down. I used CSS to keep the sub menu open when on the main categorys page, but the jQuery `slideUp()` function disables that on mouseOut. I would like to keep the sub-menu always open when on the main categories page.

```
<div id="sidebar">
 <ul>
    <li class="main">
        <a href="real_estate.php" class="real_estate">Real Estate </a>
        <ul class="sub" id="sub_real_estate">
            <li> <a href="consulting.php">Consulting Services</a></li>
            <li> <a href="investment.php">Investment</a></li>
            <li> <a href="property_mgmt.php">Property Management</a></li>
            <li> <a href="development.php">Development</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="main">
        <a href="investment.php" class="">Investment</a>
        <ul class="sub" id="sub_investment">
            <li><a href="philosophy.php">Philosophy</a></li>
          <li><a href="criteria.php">Criteria</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".main").hover(function() {
    $(".sub", this).slideDown('slow');
},
function() {
    $(".sub", this).slideUp('slow');
});
})
```

CSS

```
.sub {display:none;}

body.real_estate #sub_real_estate, body.investment #sub_investment {
display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".main").hover(function() {
        $(".sub", this).slideDown('slow');
    },
    function() {
        if(window.location.href != 'mysite.com/main-categories')
        {
            $(".sub", this).slideUp('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

Simply `alert(window.location.href);` to see what your main-categories page href is, and swap that value into the comparison I provided above.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a `class="current"` on the sub-menu on each page and use the `not()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".main").hover(function() {
    $(".sub", this).not(".current").slideDown('slow');
},
function() {
    $(".sub", this).not(".current").slideUp('slow');
});
})
```

In the CSS you then also have to remove the `display:none;` from `.current`.

Comment: Will this work if the entire menu is on one page and being included using php inside all the main pages?

Comment: Yes, as long as the CSS and Javascript is included on all those pages to.

Comment: The difference in this compared to yours is the use of `not()` and that you have to make `.current` visible in CSS with a single `display:inherit;` line fx. The script and everything else will work together in the same way as always. Why do you think it shouldn't work?

Comment: I'm confused at how I can make this work since I have the entire menu on one page and its being included in all the other pages of the website.  That's why I'm not sure how to implement this method.

Comment: Meaning, I cannot add the current class to a different sub menu on each page, since my entire menu is all on one page.

Comment: Okay, understood. Then there is just one option: To read the URL that is the only difference from the pages. You should try @AlienWebguy's answer